# Handle uncompleted file upload by API POST endpoint in asp.net core MVC

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, post, file-upload, connection

To simplify the problem let's say I have a simple asp.net mvc endpoint which receives a file. In most of the cases it will be a `.jpg` one:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("appraisal/{appraisalID}/files/{fileSubjectCode}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<AppraisalFileModel>))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ModelStateDictionary))]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAppraisalFile(int appraisalID, string fileSubjectCode, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
        file = file ?? Request.Form.Files?.FirstOrDefault();

        // intermitent code change to investigate and validate Complete File Size and Actual File Size
        var completeFileSizeHeader = Request.Headers["Complete-File-Size"];
        int.TryParse(completeFileSizeHeader, out int completeFileSize);

        if (file == null || file.Length != completeFileSize)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;

                var inputAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
                Logger.LogDebug("Complete-File-Size header doesn't much received byteArray size", file.Length, completeFileSize, inputAsString);
            }
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status411LengthRequired, "Complete-File-Size header doesn't much received byteArray size");
        }


        // some other logic..
}
```

I'm trying to prevent an edge case when somebody performs a POST request against my API `UploadAppraisalFile` endpoint and suddenly loses an internet connection which would result in sending a request with not the full file content.
My idea was to count the file size at the point where the file is uploaded, add the information about the file size as an extra HTTP-HEADER (I called it `Complete-File-Size`), and then when the request reaches the backend, count if the received file size is exactly the same as the `Complete-File-Size`.

To produce such an issue/edge case I tried:

- uploading a big file(about 16MB) and then suddenly after submitting the HTML form immediately close the browser window.
- uploading a file and then, in the Chrome browser, in the Network pane, change the uploading speed to a very minimum, then submit the form and then immediately close the browser.

When I run the debug mode, in each case I found that either: `UploadAppraisalFile` endpoint was never reached or if it was reached then always the full file was sent. For the 2nd successful case, to be 100% sure I converted the received file into base64 string and then I checked how the file looks like in https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter.

My question is: Is it even possible that the sent POST request is broken and contains not full file content due to a broken internet connection that happened suddenly during the sending process? If yes, then what's the best way to produce the issue. Cheers

Comment: Please share `some other logic`

Comment: There's a lot of dependencies in that "some other logic" code but in general, the main point is all about exactly what you wrote in the answer; so passing the file content to Cloudinary file storage in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `HttpContext.RequestAborted` as a `CancellationToken` to ALL async methods provided by .NET in `"some other logic"` part.

Let's use code you provided as an example :

```cs
await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, HttpContext.RequestAborted)
```

I don't have an access to a full method but I assume you save it to some blob storage or file system. Most of these persistence API's accept `CancellationToken` as a parameter.

**Receiving incomplete file**

I was able to achieve a "partial" file using this code and Postman.  It will basically read chunks from response stream until connection is interrupted.
As soon as I close Postman window `TaskCancelledException` is raised and stream is closed.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAppraisalFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    var appraisalfile = file ?? Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();

    if (appraisalfile != null)
    {
        var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024);
        using var stream = appraisalfile.OpenReadStream();
        while (await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, HttpContext.RequestAborted) > 0)
        {
             // Do something with buffer
             _logger.LogInformation("Total length (bytes) {0}, partial length (bytes) {1}", stream.Length, stream.Position);
        }
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is an interesting point about HttpContext.RequestAborted. So are you saying that I can only deal with an aborted request rather than a request which has uncompleted file content due to action of e.g. immediate closing the browser window ur sudden internet connection loss?

Comment: I think uncompleted file content is because `IFormFile` reads your file as a `Stream` and at some point connection is closed by a browser and there's no more data to read. But some data has already been read. With `CancellationToken` there's a guarantee that your following logic will rollback its progress.

Comment: If you want ensure that file is received completely you can read it into a `MemoryStream` and later save to cloud storage

Comment: Ok, if what you are saying is true then I could accept it is as an answer. The only thing is I was never able to achieve the case when I sent uncompleted file content in the debug mode by closing the browser. Maybe if deploy some intermittent code change to the cloud environment I can explore if the issue occurs there?

Comment: @GoldenAge it seems to me that you want to receive either nothing or complete file. Or you want to achieve something else?

Comment: No, I want to receive an uncompleted file during the test and for now I cannot achieve such a case in localhost(so I guess we are talking about situation when `HttpContext.RequestAborted` is `true`). `either nothing or complete file` is what I can experience right now in localhost.

Comment: @GoldenAge updated my answer